# Add optional parameters to URL of Docusaurus websites

Tags: javascript, docusaurus

I have a website built using [Docusaurus 2](https://v2.docusaurus.io).

I'm wondering if it is possible to add optional parameters to the URL of the site. For example, I may want to have `https://www.example.com/docs/introduction?param=abc`, then I will use the value of `param` in my components.

Is it feasible in Docusaurus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I'm understand your question, but I don't see why not. Having query params wouldn't change the URL, you just need to use `window.location.search` and parse the params, or use React Router's APIs to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

ReactJS way:

```
import { useHistory, useLocation } from '@docusaurus/router';

function YourComponent() {
   const history = useHistory();

   const setSearch = () => {
        history.push({
            search: `name=${value}`,
        });
   }

   // ...your logic
}
```